# Generating custom table view, table view cell can not fit into table view row

Tags: iphone

I created custom table view. I add the table view cell into table view but table view cell can not fit into table view row.... what I want to do for that please help me

Comment: Provide with some code so that one can help you

Comment: it would be more helpful if you can elaborate your question. preferably with code snippets..

Answer (score 0):

[Custom tableview with custom cell tutorial and working sample code](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-uiimage-and-uilabel-in-the-uitableview/)

Hope, this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and return here the height of your custom cell.